# Method that searches indexes of largest digit from table made of txt file

Tags: java, indexing

I've got a problem, because there's somewhere a problem in my code I can't resolve.
I have to make a method that searches indexes of largest digit from table made of txt file. Here's my code

```java
public static void findIndexOfLargestDigit() throws IOException {
    File file = makeNewFile();
    scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int digit;
    int largestDigit = 0;
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        digit = scanner.nextInt();
        if(digit>largestDigit) {
            largestDigit = digit;
        }
    }
    String tableToString = table.toString();
    int result = tableToString.indexOf(largestDigit);
    Integer resultInteger = new Integer(result);
    String resultToString = resultInteger.toString();
    System.out.println(resultToString);
}
```

It gives `-1` result, but I can't explain why. Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`tableToString.indexOf(largestDigit)` fails because that is a call to [`String.indexOf(int ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), but the parameter the not a `char` value but an `int` number.

Maybe you meant `tableToString.indexOf(Integer.toString(largestDigit))`, or if you prefer, you can write the same as `tableToString.indexOf(String.valueOf(largestDigit))`.

Other comments:

- You must close the `Scanner` after use. Best way is using try-with-resources.
- You should declare `digit` where used, to limit the scope to inside the loop.
- The last 3 lines is a very long way to say `System.out.println(result)`.